# In the third dimension of a numpy array, multiply the first three values by the fourth one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here is a 3-dimensional numpy array:

```py
import numpy as np
m = np.array([
  [ 
    [1,2,3,2], [4,5,6,3]
  ],
  [
    [7,8,9,4], [1,2,3,5]
  ]
])
```

For each tuple, I need to multiply the first three values by the last one (divided by 10 and rounded), and then to keep only the 3 results. For example in `[1,2,3,2]`:

- The `1` becomes: `round(1 * 2 / 10)` = `0`
- The `2` becomes: `round(2 * 2 / 10)` = `0`
- The `3` becomes: `round(3 * 2 / 10)` = `1`

So, `[1,2,3,2]` becomes: `[0,0,1]`.

And the complete result will be:

```py
[
  [ 
    [0,0,1], [1,2,2]
  ],
  [
    [3,3,4], [1,1,2]
  ]
]
```

I tried to separate the last value of each tuple in a `alpha` variable, and the 3 first values in a `rgb` variable.

```py
alpha = m[:, :, 3] / 10
rgb = m[:, :, :3]
```

But after that I'm a beginner in Python and I really don't know how to process these arrays.

A little help from an experienced Python-guy will be most welcome.

Comment: You say `I need to multiply the first three values by the last one` So for `[1,2,3,2]` why are you multiplying by `3` instead of `2`?

Comment: Are you trying to do pre-multiplied alpha?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Sorry you are right I fixed.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Maybe I'm not sure what is a "pre-multiplied alpha". I have an image with an alpha channel, I need to give it to an IA but without the alpha channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
n = np.rint(m[:,:,:3] *  m[:,:,[-1]] / 10).astype(int)

Out[192]:
array([[[0, 0, 1],
        [1, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2]]])
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert each value to an integer? I'm unsure if it is important for the AI but ideally I would like to have `[0, 0, 1]` instead of `[0., 0., 1.]` etc.

Comment: @Paleo: just use `rint`  and `astype(int)`. Check my edit.